# Fermi energy Ef changes with applied electric field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I dont understand why when we apply the electric field to the metal Ef remains the same. Ef as translation energy of electrons remains the same but we accelerate the electrons with applied electric field so the translation energy increases too? In other hand according the formula for Ef(m*,N/L^3), where m* is the effective mass depends only on material, N/L^3-number of electrons in unit volume-depends on material too. So it turns out that the Ef actually depends only on properties of the metal.

Ef defined as the the energy on the surface of the sphere created by the impulses Px,Py,Pz. So, the sphere is shifted but the radius doesnt change, then Ef should remain the same as with the unperturbed case?

Please take a look at the attached picture.

Thank you. [image]

Comment: Although I am no expert on solid state physics, I think that the Fermi Energy is not what you think it is. The radius of the the circle (or sphere in 3 D) is just the magnitude of the wave vector, not the Fermi Energy. The Fermi energy is system dependent and is defined for T = 0 K

Comment: The fermi energy, $E_F$, is defined to be the chemical potential at zero temperature. The chemical potential as far as I'm aware, is only defined for systems in thermal equilibrium, similar to the temperature. The system you seem to be picturing (one where a current is being driven by an external voltage) is not in equilibrium and so does not have a chemical potential, and so does not have a fermi energy.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I'm almost citing you that the electrons that possess Fermi Energy lying on the sphere with radius of Pf.

Comment: i think the rate of change of electric field leads to  change in electronic charge density and that effects the Fermi energy  and  this helps the flow of charge carriers -electrons.

Comment: This what I can suppose but but as you see this is not what is depicted on that picture. The Fermi translation energy (the radius of the sphere or in our case of the circle) doesnt change. The picture was taken from the book. I guess they cannot be wrong. It's me that dont get it. :)